# create a site in a staging environment Does it create problems?

Tags: force.com-sites

**I didnt create site before time in salesforce, Now i wonder and i will try to create, My question! what if i create "blabla.salesforce.com" this site Does it work from staging environment or NOT**

**i couldnt found strong information about that.**
[image]

Comment: And it will effect Production environment or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can create site in a sandbox and we have done so in the past. It won't impact production but you can create a change set to push the changes into prod.

Comment: Thanks ! the answer i want to hear